# 'Unlockable' vs. 'Unlockables'.

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was just thinking, that the tag [unlockable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlockable) should be switched to [unlockables](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unlockables).
I know it's a silly semantic, but most similar tags are in the plural form, like [weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) and [characters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) for example.

Comment: How would this go about being changed?  Would someone have to edit each of the 23 questions tagged 'unlockable'?

Comment: No, a moderator can just rename the tag in one shot. Also, [the original discussion that lead to the choice of unlockable](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105/unlockable-content-tag).

Answer (score 6):

Agreed, tags usually seem to be of the form "These questions with the same tag are about `[blank]`.", or at least a number that people will usually deal with (*a* [pc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc), *an* [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360)), etc.

Comment: I'll be making this rename later today if no opposition comes until then. It's a quick reversal, so it's fine to oppose afterwards too.